# Update Firebase database data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update my databse:

[image]

This is my code, but it doesn't seem to update the database. (Write access is set to true in Firebase settings)

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
      ref.child("items").child("1").child("itemAvailability").setValue("Not Available");
```

Java class

```
public class Item {
    String itemName;
    String itemAvailability;

    public Item(String itemName, String itemAvailability) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemAvailability = itemAvailability;
    }

    public Item() {
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemAvailability() {
        return itemAvailability;
    }

    public void setItemAvailability(String itemAvailability) {
        this.itemAvailability = itemAvailability;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is it doing if it is not updating?

Comment: @beastlyCoder no changes. I refreshed the firebase conosle, no changes

Comment: can you show the whole code you have for accessing the firebase content

Comment: @beastlyCoder added. Should I create a method and put the code inside it?

Comment: do you have  a POJO class set up( with instance variables constructor etc)

Comment: I put 1 as a string as child only takes string values. Can that be an issue? I added the pojo class code. @beastlyCoder

Comment: Aren't you missing an argument to your FirebaseApp or to the database URL in the FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with a Map Data structure.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference itemRef = ref.child("items/1/itemAvailability");
Map<String, Object> itemUpdates = new HashMap<>();
itemUpdates.put("itemAvailability", "Not Available");

itemRef.updateChildrenAsync(itemUpdates);
```

This will take the item 1's availability and update it's availability to Not Available

Comment: yes it was, i got it from this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update

Comment: i also made a typo in item, i changed it to the correct word "items"

Comment: @Efaz did this help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Firebase real-time database Insert, Update & Delete operation(CRUD).

```
//****UPDATE 
var database = firebase.database();
let userRef = database.ref('myroot/items/');
userRef.child("1").child("itemAvailability").update("Not Available").then().catch();

//****Insert 
var database = firebase.database();
let userRef = database.ref('myroot/items/');
userRef.child("1").child("itemAvailability").set("Not Available").then().catch();

//****Delete 
let itemId=1;
let userRef = database.ref('myroot/items/' + itemId);
userRef.remove().then().catch();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
      ref.child("items").child("1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
              HashMap<String, Object> updateMap = new HashMap<>();
              updateMap.put("itemAvailability", "Not Available");
              ref.updateChildren(updateMap);
              }

         @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

             }
        });
```

Might work for you.